# Running a script on my office computer without Python installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've written a script, on my personal computer, to organize some PDF files that are in my office server, in a CSV format.

However, I don't have Python installed in my office, and I don't have permission to install it. I was thinking about to run the code on browser, using something like Jupyter Notebook.

There is any way to run a script in Jupyter notebook (Browser) in a folder on the computer? I need to do this without uploading the files to Jupyter lab, and running the code on the directory.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or use the [Python exe without installing.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8gty59/portable_python_i_can_run_without_installing_on_a/)
py2exe will require setting up beforehand with an environment with Python, as it is an extension of Distutils.
Create a file called `setup.py`, with the content

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['script.py'])
```

For using python without installing:

> You can download the latest version in zip format and extract it into
>   any folder and add that folder to your PATH environment variable so
>   you can execute python from any directory or use the exact path to the
>   python exe.

Comment: py2exe is deprecated now

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Should I remove that from the answer?

Comment: well, no, but the answer answers to an unclear question and creating an executable from python is a very well known stackoverflow question & answer for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change files on a client machine (your office computer) from a browser.

Can you connect to your office computer via VPN from your PC? If so, you can run your python program from your PC once connected by giving the network path to your computer.

So, after you've connected to the VPN, if your office computer's name is `mahtorkoffice`, you can do something like `\\mahtorkoffice\c$\*path to the folder you need to run the script against*`

Comment: I don't have any admin privileges or access to connect via VPN :/